# iOS Swift - Regular Expression: Match anything including line break

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I have an HTML code like this:

```
...
<div class="list-movie-filter-item">
                                <label for="filter-sort">Sắp xếp</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="filter-sort" name="sort">
                                    <option value="updatetime" >Thời gian cập nhật</option>
                                    <option value="posttime" >Thời gian đăng</option>
                                    <option value="year" >Năm sản xuất</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-movie-filter-item">
                                <label for="filter-eptype">Hình thức</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="filter-eptype" name="eptype">
                                    <option value="">Tất cả</option>
                                    <option value="single" >Phim lẻ</option>
                                    <option value="serial" >phim bộ</option>
                                    <option value="theater" selected>Phim chiếu rạp</option>
                                    <option value="classic" >Phim kinh điển</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-movie-filter-item">
                                <label for="filter-language">Ngôn ngữ</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="filter-language" name="language">
                                    <option value="">Tất cả</option>
                                    <option value="vietnam" >Tiếng Việt</option>
                                    <option value="illustrate" >Thuyết minh</option>
                                    <option value="dubbing" >Lồng tiếng</option>
                                    <option value="subtitle" >ViệtSub</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
...
```

I want to extract the list of "filter-eptype" options. How can I use regex like this:

```
filter-eptype(.*?)<.select
```

which will then give me this result:

```
form-control" id="filter-eptype" name="eptype">
                                <option value="">Tất cả</option>
                                <option value="single" >Phim lẻ</option>
                                <option value="serial" >phim bộ</option>
                                <option value="theater" selected>Phim chiếu rạp</option>
                                <option value="classic" >Phim kinh điển</option>
                            </select
```

But the (.*?) does not match line break

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool. Use a HTML parser like [this one](https://cocoapods.org/?q=htmlreader)

Comment: I want to use regex in this case, since HTML parser does not solve my other problems